# Uploading files to remote server and batch rename

Tags: bash, files, rsync, rename, scp

I have a large set of files and need to upload them to a remote machine with specific destinations. I have a map (can be re-organised) as

```
1/1/1/file.jpg -> 2/3/4/image1.jpg
2/12/2/file.jpg -> 5/6/7/image2.jpg
3/31/31/file.jpg -> 8/9/1/image3.jpg
```

I can think of two solutions:

**Uploading to specific destinations**

```
scp /folder/1/1/1/file.jpg user@ip:/dir/2/3/4/image1.jpg
scp /folder/2/12/2/file.jpg user@ip:/dir/5/6/7/image2.jpg
scp /folder/3/31/31/file.jpg user@ip:/dir/8/9/1/image2.jpg
```

but it is not efficient to have thousands of `scp` connections.

*Question:* How can I upload multiple files in one connection (for the sake of speed) with a method like `scp`?

**Uploading with rsync and then batch rename**

I can upload the entire folder with `rsync`, which is quite fast, to a temporary folder. Then, rename the files according to the above map.

*Question:* How can I batch rename with a given map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third solution requires that all of the source files are on the same filesystem, and thus hard links can be made arbitrarily to any of the files.

Store your file map in file `filemap.txt`:

```
$ cat << EOF > filemap.txt
1/1/1/file.jpg -> 2/3/4/image1.jpg
2/12/2/file.jpg -> 5/6/7/image2.jpg
3/31/31/file.jpg -> 8/9/1/image3.jpg
EOF
```

Then use this script to create a temporary output directory named `temp` which will contain sub-directories matching the destination paths of your file map.  Each source filename will in turn be hard-linked into its proper destination path under directory `temp`.  Once `temp` is fully populated, it will be `rsync`ed to `user:ip` and then deleted from the local machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

srcD="/folder/"
destD="/dir/"

rm   -rf temp

while read  src X dest
do

        dir="$(dirname "$dest")"

        mkdir -p "temp/$dir"
        ln "$srcD$src" "temp/$dest"

done < filemap.txt

rsync -av temp/ user@ip:"$destD"

rm -rf temp
```

Comment: brilliant solution indeed, because I have to create the map file. With this idea, I directly create symbolic links instead of the map file.

Comment: your `rsync` command needs `L`.

Comment: @Googlebot Probably because you're using symbolic links, whereas my example uses hard links.

Comment: you're absolutely right. Is there any benefit to using a hard link here? I gather a soft link might be more convenient as the purpose is temporary.